# How to get match by the nearest date and calculate loss in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following table is given:

Columns

1. ID
2. Deal Date_time
3. Nominal   (where “value” >0 for a deal of the Buy type and “value” <0 for a deal of the Sell type.)
4. Exchange rate EUR/USD

There is a table:

| ID | Date_time | Nominal | EUR_USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 10:10:10 | 100 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 15.04.2021 10:11:11 | -350 | 2.45 |
| 3 | 18.05.2021 18:15:41 | 350 | 8.45 |
| 4 | 19.05.2021 00:00:00 | -790 | 3.5 |

I have second table:

1. Date_time
2. Actual Exchange rate

There is a table:

| Date_time | Actual exchange rate |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 00:00:00 | 3.6 |
| 01.04.2021 00:00:00 | 2.0 |
| 01.05.2021 00:00:00 | 8.20 |
| 01.06.2021 00:00:00 | 3 |

I need to get top 2 worst deals. For this i need to get match by nearest date. If I understand correctly, then I need to use

```
where table1.Date_time >= table2.Date_time
```

Then I get two columns with actual equivalent and nominal equivalent. And then I compare them and display the top n bad deals.

The problem is that I know how to do it in python, but I have no idea how to do it in sql....

Can you give me advice or direction for a solution?

Comment: could you elaborate on what is a bad deal and add the exact expected result set? I suspect a simple `order by desc` and `fetch first 2 rows with ties` would do

Comment: in this case, a bad deal is the one in which the difference between the real and the nominal amount is greatest.

I thought about "ORDER BY DESC" , but I didn’t really understand how I can take into account the fact that my values can be both positive and negative

Comment: How do you compute real amounts? Can you also share the expected output table given the input tables you shared in the post?

Comment: At this step, I have a problem, since I'm used to using python and there you can safely multiply tables.

Here I want to multiply the denomination by EUR_USD and Actual exchange rate. And then calculate the difference between them.

I'm sorry for the vague question

Comment: Please show us the data set you wish to produce and describe how you'd identify the worst deals.  I _think_ you want to compute each deal's (absolute value) difference of `table1.nominal * table1.eur_usd` and `table1.nominal * actual_exchange_rate_at_the_time_of_deal` and identify the two deals with the greatest difference.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: Yeah. U a right. Unfortunately i can not show set, caz its bank inofrmation

Comment: Of course you can - make up column names and values, never mention actuals (if you had not mentioned bank information nobody you would know). For example, I worked at a bank years ago and would make up account numbers form the previous week NFL scores, and amounts were passing yards. The point is create names/values that demonstrate the issue, nothing actually needs to be real.

Comment: I gave an example above. Can you see him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(target_date, date_column) AS diff
FROM table_name
WHERE DATEDIFF(target_date, date_column) >= 0
ORDER BY diff ASC
```